# Discord.py bot task loop not running in the background

Tags: python, discord

I'm new to bot programming and I can't get a task to run in the background.

The feature in question listens to an irc stream and collects data when certain posts are made.
It currently exists and runs fine if I use os.popen on a script, but I'd rather the data be part of the bot, which would make it much easier to handle. What happens when I run the @task.loop is that it runs, but the bot becomes unresponsive to chat.

Here is the entire cog (modified slightly to make it easier to read):

```
class IRC(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.index = 0
        self.bot = bot
        load_dotenv()
        token = os.getenv('IRC_TOKEN')
        nickname = os.getenv('IRC_NICK')
        server = os.getenv('IRC_SERVER')
        port = os.getenv('IRC_PORT')
        channel = os.getenv('IRC_CHANNEL')
        self.sock = socket.socket()
        self.sock.connect((server, port))
        self.sock.send(f"PASS {token}\n".encode('utf-8'))
        self.sock.send(f"NICK {nickname}\n".encode('utf-8'))
        self.sock.send(f"JOIN {channel}\n".encode('utf-8'))
        print("Listening to IRC")
        self.reader.start()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=0)
    async def reader(self):
        resp = self.sock.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
        # print(resp)
        if resp.startswith('PING'):
            self.sock.send("PONG\n".encode('utf-8'))
        elif len(resp) > 0:
            if resp.startswith("listening phrase"):
                print(resp)
        else: pass    

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(IRC(bot))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I will guess: `recv()` as default  is blocking command and it may wait for data so `loop` can also wait (even if it async function) and it can block all code. `recv` is not asynchronous command (even if you try to use `async recv()`) and it may need to be run in separated thread. You can also try to use module `select` to check if there are data in socket before you try to use `recv()` - but it probably works only on Linux and it may not be easy. OR you can try to find module with async socket.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for pointing me in a direction.

Comment: So, it seems I need to use asyncio directly (which I think Discord.py is built on). I'm currently reading code for an irc client built with asyncio that I think I can make work for this project.